# How to filter datas in OpenERP using domain list

Tags: filter, expression, odoo

I want to filter recods in OPenERP using domain filter expression

In the recored I have a field of list of users, so i want get the record where the user logged in the list

```
[(user.id , 'in' , 'user_ids')]
```

**This doesn't work**

it return this error :

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2356, in search
    return self._search(cr, user, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, context=context, count=count)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4846, in _search
    self._apply_ir_rules(cr, user, query, 'read', context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4728, in _apply_ir_rules
    rule_where_clause, rule_where_clause_params, rule_tables = rule_obj.domain_get(cr, uid, self._name, mode, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_rule.py", line 156, in domain_get
    query = self.pool.get(model_name)._where_calc(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, dom, active_test=False)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4676, in _where_calc
    e = expression.expression(cr, user, domain, self, context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 632, in __init__
    self.parse(cr, uid, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 759, in parse
    field_path = left.split('.', 1)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Please help me.

Comment: How can we achieve this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722919/how-to-use-functional-field-in-record-rule][1]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your domain syntax is wrong.

It should be `[('user_ids', '=' , user.id)]`

1. Each tuple in the search domain needs to have 3 elements, in the form: `('field_name', 'operator', value)`, where:
2. **field_name** must be a valid name of field of the object model, possibly following many-to-one relationships using dot-notation, e.g 'street' or 'partner_id.country' are valid values.
3. **operator** must be a string with a valid comparison operator from this list: 
   `=, !=, >, >=, <, <=, like, ilike, in, not in, child_of, parent_left, parent_right`
             The semantics of most of these operators are obvious.
             The `child_of` operator will look for records who are children or grand-children of a given record,
             according to the semantics of this model (i.e following the relationship field named by
             `self._parent_name`, by default `parent_id`.
4. **value** must be a valid value to compare with the values of **field_name**, depending on its type.

Domain criteria can be combined using 3 logical operators than can be added between tuples:  '**&**' (logical AND, default), '**|**' (logical OR), '**!**' (logical NOT).
        These are **prefix** operators and the arity of the '**&**' and '**|**' operator is 2, while the arity of the '**!**' is just 1. Be very careful about this when you combine them the first time.

Here is an example of searching for Partners named *ABC* from Belgium and Germany whose language is not english ::

```
[('name','=','ABC'),'!',('language.code','=','en_US'),'|',('country_id.code','=','be'),('country_id.code','=','de')]
```

The **'&'** is omitted as it is the default, and of course we could have used **'!='** for the language, but what this domain really represents is::

```
(name is 'ABC' AND (language is NOT english) AND (country is Belgium OR Germany))
```

Comment: Excellent. Such a detailed explanation is missing from the docs.

Comment: Great answer! Can I ask how you figure things out in Odoo while documentation is poor? What are your go to resources? Thanks

Comment: I used to go into ORM files, checking all the classes and methods and the code.

Comment: Hi @SudhirArya, I am needing a domaing based on two conditions:
1.  either product should exist in "product_ids"
2. or it should exist in "suggested_product_ids" with ('is_psa','!=',True),

where *_ids fields are m2m and 'is_psa' a boolean Field. I have tried domain below with no luck. Thanks in advance.

domain="['|',('id','in',product_ids[0][2])('is_psa','!=',True),('id','in','suggested_product_ids[0][2]'))]"

Comment: You should try this:

domain="['|',('id', 'in', product_ids[0][2]), ('id', 'in', 'sugge‌​sted_product_ids[0][2]'), ('is_psa', '!=', True))]"

Comment: @SudhirArya  can you help me to apply to domain on invoice field                                                                                                   <field name="sup_refund_entries" nolabel="1" domain="['|',('period_id','=',period_ids),(,'&amp;',('date_invoice','&gt;',date_from),('date_invoice','&lt;',date_to)),'&amp;',('type','=','in_refund'),('state','=','open')] " > but its not working well can u tell me what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In a simple case this is right, BUT if you want to filter current object by its functional field, you'll be very surprised that code in function of this field will not execute; instead fnct_search part of this field will be executed, that will allow you to do various things.

**Left part** of filter expression is evaluated in context of *current object*, and **right part** — in context of *inner context* (read current user).

**Left part** is evaluated **after** right, so you can add a functional field to a user model, make some calculations there, and then receive those calculations on the object's side and take them into account.

See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21336100/674557