# How to set field domain on computed data in a view?

Tags: odoo

I would like to restrict a many2one(res.partner) fields to show only values belonging to a given partner category.

If I would know the category id, then I could add this to my view:

```
<field name="insurer" domain="[('category_id', 'in', 1)]"/>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know the category id, but I create it inside my data xml.

As a result my best idea until now is to define an onchange handler, that sets the domain.

```
def onchange_insurance(self, cr, uid, ids, first_field):
    biztosito_category = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object(cr, uid, 'ensure_base', 'biztosito_partner_category').id
    return {
            'domain': {
              'insurer':  [('category_id', '=', biztosito_category)],
            },
    }
```

Is there a way to have such a computed domain into the view code without an onchange handler?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `category_id` field in your view then you can use it in your domain.

Try following code:

```
<field name="insurer" domain="[('category_id', '=', category_id)]"/>
```

See [more about domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14618598/1155500).

Comment: Thank you, I know this. The question is how to specify the last part of the domain, if you don't know your category id yet, as it's created in the same xml.