# Search through records in database

Tags: odoo

I have this price that I fetch from another class (lets say 500 for this example) and I want to know how I can use the search function to get the ID back from the list below.

For example I have this in my database, I want to use the search function to get me the id where my price is bigger then the MIN_PRICE and lower then my MAX_PRICE. In my case where the price is 500 I want it to return ID 2.

SQL Example: `WHERE price > MIN_PRICE ANDnd price > MAX_PRICE`

```
ID     MIN_PRICE       MAX_PRICE
 1             0             100
 2           101            1000
 3          1001           10000
 4         10001          100000
```

I've tried the following with the min price but with no success:

```
self.search(cr, uid, [(self.browse(cr, uid, ids).min_price,'in', price_untaxed)])
```

Comment: Please elaborate more your question

Comment: @DeftSoftInformatics I don't know what I can add more. I just need to get the ID where my price is in beween the MIN_PRICE and the MAX_PRICE

Comment: Use between clause of Mysql.

Comment: @DeftSoftInformatics I know I have it in SQL code but I wanted to use the self.search function for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search takes a search domain and returns a recordset of matching records.

A domain is a list of criteria, each criterion being a triple (either a list or a tuple) of (field_name, operator, value).

For more about domain:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14618598/3374651

For v8:

```
self.search([('price', '=', MIN_PRICE), ('price', '=', MAX_PRICE)]) # Will return list of matched recordset
```

For v7:

```
self.pool.get("model_name").search(cr, uid, [('price', '=', MIN_PRICE), ('price', '=', MAX_PRICE)], context=context) # Will return list of matched ids
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
self.search(cr, uid, [('price','>','MIN_PRICE'),('price','<','MAX_PRICE')],context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

In search method you need to pass domain (criteria for filtration).
Search method gives you list of ids [] back.

```
self.search(cr, uid, [('price','>','MIN_PRICE'),('price','<','MAX_PRICE')],context=context)
```

or

```
self.pool.get('model_name').search(cr, uid, [('price','>','MIN_PRICE'),('price','<','MAX_PRICE')],context=context)
```